# Layout, CardView e RecyclerView

Tags: android

Bom dia, sou iniciante em desenvolvimento android, estou com duvida, gostaria de uma sugestão.

Estou fazendo um aplicativo similar ao Trello, porém não sei o que utilizar.

Terei várias listas que poderão ser navegadas na horizontal e dentro das listas podem ser adicionados cartões como mostra a imagem, quais recursos posso utilizar? Um CardView para as listas e dentro do CardView uma Recyclerview para adicionar os cartões?

[image: Quadros Trello]

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar dos dois pois eles servem pra propósitos diferentes. Resumidamente, o `RecyclerView` serve para representar listas de dados, e o `CardView` serve para mostrar dados de um ítem.

Quanto a como utilizar, eu sugiro o seguinte: partindo da ideia que cada item dessa lista horizontal seja um objeto `Board` (exemplo) e que um `Board` tenha *N* objetos `Cards` associados, você vai precisar de duas listas, ou seja, dois `RecyclerView`s, um pra montar a lista horizontal de `Boards` e outra pra montar a lista de `Card`s de cada `Board`. Porém, como cada `Card` tem informações próprias (por exemplo, descrição) você vai precisar mostrar elas dentro de um `CardView`.

Sendo assim, você teria algo parecido como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: fiz dessa forma e consegui, muito obrigado!